# Resources for Teaching Logic to Primary School Children?

Tags: primary-education, logic, resource-request, resources

What are some books or other resources for teaching primary school children logic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a book that should fit the bill: [Camp Logic](https://naturalmath.com/camplogic/), by Mark Saul and Sian Zelbo.

[Disclaimer: This comes from my publisher. I am guessing that it's good.]

Comment: I have this book, and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for three terms logic, elementary, and school came up with the following relevant hits on the first page:

1. Page with links to many other resources on this topic:

https://cathyduffyreviews.com/homeschool-extras/critical-thinking-logic

2. Another page listing several logic resources for young children (emphasis is on age appropriate puzzles).

https://ourjourneywestward.com/my-favorite-logic-resources/

3. 1965 journal article on logic teaching for elementary school:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/41186878?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

4. Hacker thread discussing teaching logic in elementary school (a university teacher argues no in well done post):

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1867769

5. Reddit thread with similar debate (but many more posts) on the value proposition for this topic at this age:

https://www.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/1wsalo/i_think_that_we_should_teach_formal_logic_to_very/

P.s.  If you do your own Google Search, about 30% of the hits will be relevant (some are on the rapper Logic or on school discipline!), but you can quickly weed through that based on the preview descriptions.  So maybe worth while going to page 2 or 3 of the Google search if you want more info.  But I would start with the subordinate hits from items (1) and (2) above.

P.s.s.  I am skeptical of teaching real rigorous logic in this setting.  Although I was part of New Math and got the Venn diagrams and Boolian stuff in elementary school.  Didn't do me any harm I guess.  One of the problems with teaching real logical methods is that students may not have enough other references.  For example, if you teach truth tables than students may not have much experience with tabular data in general.  Probably better off to just work on that instead.  But idonno!

Comment: See also my answer to [Logic and set theory textbook for high school](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641236/logic-and-set-theory-textbook-for-high-school/658674#658674), especially the second half of my answer.